# Why /#/ doesnt work in dnsmasq?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

i am trying to implement captive portal with dnsmasq.
In dnsmasq config
`address=/#/10.42.0.1` doesn't work,
so i have to use ugly

```
address=/com/10.42.0.1
address=/uk/10.42.0.1
address=/org/10.42.0.1
address=/gov/10.42.0.1 ...
```

This redirects all listed domains fine, if in browser you go anywhere, however captive portal browser doesn't pop up by itself (checked no mac win and linux), and there is problem if site redirects to https (like facebook), my portal page is http only.

So how should it be setup correcltly to replace all domain names  or even just make browser pop up with captive portal page?

UPD: acording to man page

> --address=/#/1.2.3.4 will always return 1.2.3.4 for any query not answered from /etc/hosts or DHCP and not sent to an upstream
> nameserver by a more specific --server directive.

So how can i make sure there is no upstream hosts for the NetworkManager - dnsmasq?

Comment: Maybe `#` is being interpreted as the start of an inline comment.  I would try `\#`.

Comment: I assume the missing `d` is a transcription error when adding the detail to your post… ? `adress=/#/10.42.0.1`

Comment: sorry it was just typo here, in config it's fine

Comment: Separate the browser redirection from the DNS activity. `dnsmasq` only handles DNS, so test that in isolation. For various values of `testDomain` such as `cnn.com`, `bbc.co.uk`. `facebook.com`, etc, does `dig @yourDNSserver testDomain` return expected values or not? Then you can concentrate your investigation in the appropriate corner

Comment: @roaima thanks for your response, /#/ doesnt work - i mean if i leave only this line in config and do nslookup facebook.com - i still recieve real facebook ip . When i add /com/ line  - it works fine and i recieve local captive portal ip. (browser behaves consistently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me, version `Dnsmasq version 2.80`. I have just this in my `dnsmasq.conf` and every domain lookup returns `1.2.3.4`

```
domain-needed
no-resolv
no-poll
no-hosts
cache-size=150
no-negcache
local-ttl=30
address=/#/1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Do you have hotspot either?

Comment: I've just run up severely reduced configuration file on a spare system I have. I use dnsmasq, but not as a hotspot. This configuration returns the same IP address `1.2.3.4` for any query I can throw at it